# How to find whether a image is present in the docker repository

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Trying to pull a docker image in my local repo. 
Command used:

```
docker pull buzybox:1.24
Error response from daemon: repository buzybox not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

**My questions:**

*1:How to find the repository name which am connected with?*

*2.Whats the access issue in the error its talking about? Do we also have any kind of access issues in the default repo?? How to find that out?*

*3.How to change the repo if in case i dont find a image in my currect repo.*

*4.Do we have any web portal from where we can search if the image is present in repository.*

**Output id docker info :**

```
docker info
 Containers: 5
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 5
 Images: 2
Server Version: 17.06.2-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk 
syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170
runc version: 810190ceaa507aa2727d7ae6f4790c76ec150bd2
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.41-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.941GiB
Name: moby
ID: RJWZ:HXFZ:5FQX:V2AB:YAXP:BKSU:RLQH:H24C:LNUD:USDA:VIF7:W2M3
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 15
 Goroutines: 26
 System Time: 2018-01-28T06:34:45.7011515Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Thanks in advance Guys!!

Nilotpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not connect to a repository. You connect to a registry. You are probably connected to https://index.docker.io/v1/ but to be sure, you can run `sudo docker info` and look for the registry line. The repository in your case is `buzybox` and you are trying to download the image with tag `1.24` from that repository.
2. The access issue is probably that you mispelled `busybox` (notice the 's' instead of a 'z').
3. To log into a different registry, then run

   ```
   docker login https://<YOUR-DOMAIN>:8080
   ```

   and then make sure to specify the new registry when you download an image like so:

   ```
   docker pull <YOUR-DOMAIN>:8080/busybox:1.24
   ```

Comment: Is it always port 8080?

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot for the answers? Do we have any command just to check whether the image is present in the registry? I dont want to pull to local.

Comment: I don't think so. In fact, 5000 might be more common.

Comment: Gr8!! Thanks for the info!!

Comment: I think searching is done by `sudo docker search <REPOSITORY-NAME>` (but this only works for the Docker Hub registry). You could also do a `sudo docker pull <IMAGE-NAME>` and then press CTRL-C if it starts to download. Googling seems to show some `curl` incantations that will do a search for private registries.